# determine if date range falls between another date range - sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime

I am trying to find out if there is a way in sql (t-sql preferred) to identify if a date range falls between another date range.

for purposes of my example:
daterange1 = i have a defined date range, dates are  1/1/2012 - 1/5/2012
daterange2 = i have two other dates to work with, lets say 1/3/2012 and 1/4/2012

i am trying to have this to use in a CASE statement for something like this

```
CASE 
    WHEN daterange1 = 0 then result1
    WHEN daterange2 falls within daterange1 then result2 
    END as datestuff
```

is this possible in SQL? I'm really stumped on this one, i know how to figure out if a single date falls between a range, but how can it be done with a date range? the answer doesnt necessarily need to be in a CASE statement but it is preferred.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

How can you get `daterange1 = 0`, since it's a range, i.e. 2 values?

The proper test for overlapping dates is

```
CASE WHEN @range1start <= @range2end
      and @range2start <= @range1end THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

If you mean that daterange2 must fall ENTIRELY within daterange1, then

```
CASE WHEN @range1start <= @range2start
      and @range2end <= @range1end THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: thank you, i thought it had to be something like that, just couldnt figure it out

Answer (score -1):

select * 
from t 
where ( beginningdate between startdate and closedate 
OR endingdate between startdate and closedate 
OR ( beginningdate < startdate and endingdate >= closedate ) );